# CISCO ASA: Static external 1:1 NAT, but also with Internal Access

Tags: nat, cisco-asa

We have a NAT rule in our ASA 5525-X here, which basically makes it so that 1.2.3.4 on the outside and 10.1.9.10 on the inside are essentially NAT'd.  That is, you can reach 1.2.3.4 on the outside, and get served the data at 10.1.9.10.

This is all fine and dandy, but we can't access 10.1.9.10 internally now; I'm not entirely sure how to fix this so we can access it both internally *and* externally.

Anyone got any pointers?

---

We're working with ASA version 9.1(7), running on an ASA 5525-X.  The ASA is in Routed mode.

Comment: Use real IPs. ;) But what version of ASA and what platform is this? The answer will be different depending on that.

Comment: @ewwhite fun fact: 10.1.9.10 is the actual internal address lol.  I am forced to obfuscate the actual public IP in this case, by policy.  Getting you the information you need shortly, the systems are slow :P

Comment: Question really belongs on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com IMO.

Comment: @TheCleaner It seems to me this would remain on topic here, but *also* be on topic at Network Engineering - this would fit into this part of the Server Fault help center's "what's on topic" here:  "managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks"

Comment: This is on topic. I had to solve this at one of my locations yesterday.

Comment: @ewwhite interesting!  I can't wait to hear from you as to how you solved it heh.

Comment: Please provide the requested information ;)

Comment: @ewwhite I've stated the ASA and model - which do you mean by "platform"?

Comment: I don't disagree that it is on topic for both sites, but I think our "what's on topic" here on SF should be updated to remove networking in 2017 and push folks to the site dedicated to it now.  But yes, at the moment it is on topic and Ed can hook you up with a fix it would seem.